# How do I fill a list in python with user-defined class instances?

Tags: python

So I'm trying to fill a list with instances of a class that I defined myself, but I keep getting an error when I try to access any element in the list.  The code is below.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
class Population:
"""total population of workers"""
    workerl = []

    def __init__(self, p, workers):
        # probability of a worker becoming unemployed
        # low in booms, high in recessions, could be a proxy for i
        self.p = p
        self.workers = workers
        workerl = []
        for i in range(workers):
            print i #test
            x = Worker()
            workerl.append(x)

p = 0
workers = 0

def showUR():
    """displays number of unemployed workers in a population"""
    ur = 0
    for worker in workers:
        if worker.isemployed == true:
            ur = ur + 1
    print ur

def advance(time, p):
    """advances one unit of time"""



# population as an array of workers     
class Worker:
    """a worker in a population"""
    isemployed = True

x = Population(.2, 100) 
print x.p
print x.workerl
if x.workerl[0].isemployed:
    print "worker 1 is employed"
```

Comment: Two tips: format your code so that it's syntactically valid Python (indentation, etc), and post the exact error you're getting (formatted as code too).

Comment: Ah, I just realised that your indentation is screwy because you've got some tabs in there. Edit your code to convert them to spaces :)

Answer (score 2):

Your program is flawed on oh so many levels.

```
class Population:
"""total population of workers""" # <-- indentation error
    workerl = [] # <-- class attribute, never used

    def __init__(self, p, workers):
        # probability of a worker becoming unemployed
        # low in booms, high in recessions, could be a proxy for i
        self.p = p
        self.workers = workers
        workerl = [] # <-- local variable, should be self.workerl
        for i in range(workers):
            print i #test
            x = Worker()
            workerl.append(x)

p = 0 # <-- module variable, never used
workers = 0 # <-- module variable, never used

def showUR(): # <-- should be a method of population
    """displays number of unemployed workers in a population""" # <-- does the opposite, i.e., shows the number of EMPLOYED workers
    ur = 0
    for worker in workers: # should be self.workerl, not workers
        if worker.isemployed == true: # <-- typo, should be: True
            ur = ur + 1
    print ur

def advance(time, p):
    """advances one unit of time"""



# population as an array of workers # <-- Python lists are not arrays
class Worker:
    """a worker in a population"""
    isemployed = True # <-- class atrribute, when set to False ALL workers become unemployed at once

x = Population(.2, 100) 
print x.p
print x.workerl
if x.workerl[0].isemployed:
    print "worker 1 is employed"
```

And this is how your program should probably look like (sans comments):

```
class Worker(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.is_employed = True


class Population(object):

    def __init__(self, probability, number_of_workers):
        self.probability = probability
        self.workers = [Worker() for each in range(number_of_workers)]

    def showUR(self):
        print sum(not worker.is_employed for worker in self.workers)


x = Population(.2, 100)
print x.probability
print len(x.workers)
print x.workers
if x.workers[0].is_employed:
    print "worker 1 is employed"
```

Answer (score 0):

You created function-local variable `workerl`, correctly filled it in and forgot it.

Remember, that you always have to write `self.` (or whatever your instance parameter was) to access members in python. Also you can read class member via instance, so `self.workerl`/`x.workerl` will evaluate to it, but to set it you have to call `Population.workerl =`, because `self.workerl =` would override it in the instance.